# Sql UPDATE on link click

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a one value when a user clicks on a link.

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments a LEFT JOIN pins b ON a.pin_id = b.id INNER     JOIN board c on b.board_id = c.id WHERE a.to_id = '$myid' AND a.status = 'unviewed'") 
or die(mysql_error()); while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Print "<li>";
Print "<a href='/board/pins/".$info['board_id']."/".$info['pin_id']."'>";
Print "<img src='".$info['pin_url']."' width='50' align='left'>";
Print "<font size='1'>comment received on ".$info['date']."</font></a>";
Print "Collection: ".$info['board_name']."</li>";
} 
?>
```

The link is the one above.

how can I edit the above code to include an update query `"UPDATE comments SET status='viewed' WHERE to_id = '$myid' AND id='$postid'"` when the link is clicked?

EDIT:

this is my mark_viewed.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX","XXX");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// get values sent from address bar
$myid=$_GET['myid'];
$postid=$_GET['postid'];

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE comments SET status='viewed' WHERE to_id ='$myid' AND id='$postid'");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And my the send page:

```
<?php  // display of the notifications dropdown menu
$query_select = "SELECT * FROM comments a LEFT JOIN pins b ON a.pin_id = b.id LEFT JOIN     board c on b.board_id = c.id WHERE a.to_id = '$myid' AND a.status = 'unviewed' ORDER BY     a.date DESC";
$result_select = mysql_query($query_select) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
    $rows[] = $row;
foreach($rows as $row){ 
    $myid = $row['user_id']; // my id
    $name = $row['board_name']; // collection name
    $boardid = $row['board_id']; // collection id
    $postid = $row['pin_id']; // post id
    $url = $row['pin_url']; // image url
    echo "<li><a href='/board/pins/$boardid/$postid' data-myid='$myid' data-    postid='$postid' class='markviewed'>";
    echo "<img src='$url' height='50' width='50'>";
    echo "New comment in $name.";
    echo "</a></li>";
}
?>
```

I have the JS in the head of the same page but it isn't working. The varibles are fine on this page `$myid` and `$postid` but they aren't being sent/received on mark_viewed.php

Comment: by AJAX is the most effective and "modern" way

Comment: ajax or a get attribute in the link URL

Comment: can you be more specific with AJAX? I know using the AJAX get or post may work but any helpful examples of where I can find the right code at to make a start from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (AJAX as suggested in comments). It assumes What it basically does is:

1. Print relevant ids into html  as attributes.
2. Binds a listener to click event on those links
3. After pinging http://domain.com/mark_viewed.php (file that does the query updating comments as viewed) it redirects the browser to the desired location (/board/pins/...)

```
//html part
<?php
$myid = 1234;
$postid = 333;
//echo prepared link with ids in it's data-attributes
echo '<a href="/board/pins/"'.$info['board_id'].'/'.$info['pin_id'].'"  
   data-myid="' . $myid . '" 
   data-postid="' . $postid . '" 
   class="markviewed">mark ids as viewed and go to /board/pins/...</a>';
?>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   //bind a listener to "click" event on links with class "markviewed"
   $('a.markviewed').click(function(event) {

      //prevent default behavior just in case
      event.preventDefault();

      //get ids from clicked <a>
      var myid = $(this).attr('data-myid');
      var postid = $(this).attr('data-postid');

      //ping the address to mark clicked link as viewed
      $.ajax('http://domain.com/mark_viewed.php?myid=' + myid + '&postid=' + postid);

      //redirect to the link in the href attribute
      window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');

   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So as I understand it, if a user has 3 unviewed messages, displayed as 3 links, once he/she clicks onto one it updates the db in mark_viewed.php then redirects to the page where the unviewed message is? Then the user only has 2 unviewed messages.

Comment: Move the js to the bottom of the page or change `$('a.markviewed').click(..)` to `$('a.markviewed').on('click', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: Tried both but still only clicks through to the link without updating. You you think the problem is with mark_viewed.php?

Comment: If it moves to another link, the problem is in JS. The event is probably not attached. Move the code to the end of the html (after all links are printed) and try again.